# basic calculation referencing multiple sources.

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10I_0xtV2SlBObJxh_WF-fDgmS_PlNqUBDp4csy-Olzg/edit#gid=422336862)

im trying to add max grams able to purchase without spoilage next to the item listed on Diet page. example: chicken eggs | 1149.12g <-- ((Cal from diet page 78.25)*(shelf life 21)/(cal/100g 143)*100=1149.12. also i might try to divide that if 2 or more items are needed in the same category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Diet!F2 please try:

```
=100*vlookup(vlookup(E2,Data!A:B,2,0),A:B,2,0)*vlookup(E2,Data!A:D,4,0)/vlookup(E2,Data!A:F,6,0)
```

and copy down to suit.

Comment: yea it seems to work but it only adds the one result for chicken eggs. im looking for something that finds the word in the list created in Diet and gives a result, right now the only 2 are chicken eggs and sesame seeds.

Comment: thanks! this works! you guys rock. it completely alleviated my "calculations" page. awesome

Comment: actually is there a way to divide it by the number of instance on the final list?
Chicken eggs | 574.6
Duck eggs    | 574.6